# How to insert more than 2000 char in Oracle column of type Varchar2(4000 char) from Java Code

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc, varchar2

I am trying to insert 2000 char(ASCII char should take 1 byte only) into column of type Varchar2(4000 char) using Spring JDBC Template. But I am always getting the following error

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.

I have tried using the below properties in my connection configuration but of no use.

1. useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8
2. oracle.jdbc.RetainV9LongBindBehavior=true

Although I can insert the same text by running insert query on  oracle sql developer.

Below are relevant configuration details

- NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8,
- NLS_RDBMS_VERSION 12.1.0.2.0
- Driver version 12.1.0.2

Comment: From the error message, it seems that you are trying to insert a numeric value in a varchar column. Please add the relevant java code.

Comment: You will get the same error when you try to insert more characters than actual limit of column.

Comment: @Berger No. A `LONG` is not a number: not in Oracle. From the documentation: *Columns defined as LONG* ***can store variable-length character data containing up to 2 gigabytes of information.*** *LONG data is text data that is to be appropriately converted when moving among different systems.* - it seems the OP is trying to insert a text that is too long to fit into a VARCHAR2.

Comment: @Berger Numerics are not allowed to insert into varchar?

Comment: @BackSlash : Ow okay, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Ankursingh It seems the data you are trying to insert exceeds 4000 bytes (which is the maximum amount you can store in a VARCHAR2). Are you 100% sure all your characters are ASCII characters? Are you sure you have at most 4000 characters? You could try printing `yourString.getBytes().length`: if this exceeds `4000`, that data is not going to fit in a VARCHAR2.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question and the Java code you use to insert the value. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) [edit] your question do **not** post code in comments

Comment: @BackSlash  i can insert the same text using insert query

Comment: @Ankursingh So the error might be in your code, maybe in how you create/handle your string. Do that test, please.

Comment: @BackSlash In java anyways every char will take 2 bytes but oracle driver should convert this string according to encoding of Data Base and ASCII characters should be allocated 1 byte

Comment: LONG data type is no longer supported by Oracle. As I remember it's was always tricky to work with it even in PL/SQL. Try to use CLOB.

Comment: @AnkurSingh No, that's wrong. Java uses UTF, so characters have different sizes (1-4 bytes). See this [example](https://ideone.com/niRqn9). "abc" takes 3 bytes (one byte per character), while three chinese characters take 9 bytes (because it's a multibyte character, 3 bytes per char). Again, please do that test. If the result is > 4000, your string is invalid. And no, java is not the issue. The issue is in how you handle the string.

Comment: @BackSlash checked myString.getBytes().length it's 2006